# Boot issue after re-installing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a desktop PC with 128GB SSD drive, 4TB HDD and 256GB SSD drive.

Up until a few weeks ago, I had Windows 7 Home 64-bit installed on the 128GB drive. Then, I upgraded it to Win 10. Yesterday, I re-installed Windows 7 on the other SSD (the 256GB one).

Now, when I reboot the PC, it asks me to choose an OS to start the computer with. If it was giving me the option to choose between Windows 7 and Windows 10, that would have been very logical and even great for me, but the *two options are the same ("Windows 7") and both lead to the same installed OS* (Win 7 on the second SSD).

This means that now I cannot seem to get my PC to run with the Windows 10 installed on the first SSD (problem #1)

Even if I disregard this issue and want to continue just with the new Win 7, I don't need these options during booting and want it to start off immediately on the Windows 7 installed (problem #2).

BTW, If I disable the second SSD drive in the BIOS, I get an error message when booting saying there is *no OS to run the computer on*...

BTW #2, Even when I change the order of the booting device in the BIOS (and both drives are enabled, of course), it still loads the same two options as mentioned here, and still both of them lead to the same Win 7...

Comment: Free upgrading to Windows 10 uses your already installed Windows licence key. Please remember you're trying to use same key simultaneously on different OS, which is not allowed.

Comment: This is why I cannot boot my PC with the Win 10 any more?? If so, How can I get rid of the two (same) options to boot from and have the new Win 7 come up immediately at startup?

Comment: Possibly not. But when the licence is checked against Microsoft servers, you may be asked to enter the product key in any one of the Windows version.

Comment: I don't think this has got anything to do with licensing and product keys. When I re-installed Win 7, I have activated it with my license key and everything went through just fine. I am having issues with booting the PC with the OS installed on it, as I described in the question itself...

Comment: Looks like the boot data is corrupted on your first SSD where Windows 10 was installed. Do you have Win10 iso or bootable media?
 Backup the boot configuration with `bcdedit /export <filename>`   What is shown in your Windows 7's `msconfig > Boot (tab)` You may try removing the **not current OS** and **not default OS** entry, ie keep the entry which says its **default OS, current OS**. If the entry says its not current OS but default, reboot and select the `Windows 7` that you didnt select last time and verify this again.

Comment: If in doubt, reply back.

Comment: I just deleted the "old" Windows 10 installation from the boot configuration under msconfig and now my PC starts of with just Windows 7 immediately. Thanks!

Comment: That's nice. So, do you want to restore Windows 10?

Comment: No, thank you! :) For the time being, I'm gonna stay with the good old Windows 7. Right now, I don't have a real reason to upgrade, especially after what I've went through with that. Thanks for your help! Btw, why don't you post your comment as an answer to the current question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the boot sector data is corrupted on your first SSD where Windows 10 was installed. Do you have Win10 iso or bootable media? You may need that  to fix MBR/boot sector data..

Here is a solution for avoiding dual 'Windows entries':

Backup the boot configuration with `bcdedit /export <filenamepath>`

What is shown in your Windows 7's `msconfig > Boot (tab)` ?

You may try removing the **not current OS** and **not default OS** entry, ie keep the entry which says its **default OS, current OS**.
 If the entry says its not current OS but default, reboot and select the `Windows 7` that you didn't select last time and verify this again.